# Karma Test Adapter for Visual Studio, using requirejs no working

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, requirejs, karma-runner

I am running into a situation when using requirejs for appliction/unit tests, using the method provided here https://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html.

When trying to use the Karma VS Test adpater (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4cd59e4a-82e8-4b4e-8302-d102fc81b090), I am encountering the following error(s), in VS Output Window

```
[Karma] [Discover] 1 tests discovered in 1 test containers
========== Discover test finished: 1 found (0:00:01.678) ==========
------ Run test started ------
An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://karmatestadapter/': One or more errors occurred.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: values
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:00.083) ==========
```

and in a browser (like chrome)

```
require.js:165 Uncaught Error: Module name "../App/Password/password" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])(…)makeError @ require.js:165localRequire @ require.js:1429requirejs @ require.js:1791(anonymous function) @ TestUnitTests.js:3
main.test.js:35 load complete
```

my main.test.js

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /UnitTests\/.*.js$/;

var pathToModule = function (path) {
var returnValue = path.replace(/^\/base\//, '').replace(/.js$/, '');
return returnValue;
};

Object.keys(window.karma.files).forEach(function (file) {
if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
// Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
allTestFiles.push(pathToModule(file));
}
});

requirejs.config({
// Karma serves files from '/base'
baseUrl: '/base',

deps: allTestFiles,

paths: {
    'jquery.mockjax': 'Libraries/jquery.mockjax/jquery.mockjax'
},

shim: {
    'jquery.mockjax': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        init: function (m) { }
    }
},

// start test run, once Require.js is done
callback: function () {
    console.log('load complete');
    window.__karma__.start();
}
});
```

What I think is happening, is the VS plugin is starting the karma server, when the code (main.test.js) is expecting to do it manually in the require callback.

i've cross posted on github project as well, https://github.com/MortenHoustonLudvigsen/KarmaTestAdapter/issues/60

I am wondeirng if anyone else has encountered this issue, or has been able to make a similar situation work witht his plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar random issue where all the test would not execute one time but they would the next time. So I went ahead and disabled the "Karma Test Adapter" extension in the Visual Studio 2015 Extensions and Updates dialog. This resolved my issue.